# BottomSheet below appbar with appbar_scrolling_behaviour

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout, bottom-sheet

I would like to have my `bottomsheet` expanded only up to `appbar`. I have `viewpager` with tabs, and `viewpager` has `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`, so then list inside it is scrolled the `toolbar` is collapsed. But the bottom sheet is expanded, which is the behaviour I do not want to have. Basically I would like to have collapsed `bottomsheet` stay in place with the same height, and in expanded mode it should expand only up to `toolbar`, no matter if the `toolbar` is collapsed or not.

Here is how my xml looks like. This works, but the bottom sheet also reacts this way to `appbar` collapsing.

If I remove behaviour from second `CoordinatorLayout` the `bottomsheet` stays in place, but gets expanded to full screen.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/loadingContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

      ... content with viewpager

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:behavior_hideable="false"
            app:behavior_peekHeight="55dp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: me too facing the same issue did you got any solution?

Comment: See my answer below. I only managed to fix this by implementing my own BottomSheetBehaviour which handles childs layouts

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The view is not associated with BottomSheetBehavior please post your xml code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually fixed this myself by writing my own Behaviour for the bottomSheet to recalculate itself. Also placed all elements inside the CoordinatorLayout.

```
public class BottomSheetBehaviour extends AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior {

    public BottomSheetBehaviour () { }

    public BottomSheetBehaviour (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof AppBarLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        setDimensions((CoordinatorLayout) child, child.getLayoutParams().width,
            parent.getHeight() - (int) getOffset(parent));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChild(final CoordinatorLayout parent, final View child, final int layoutDirection) {
        final List<View> dependencies = parent.getDependencies(child);
        final View header = findFirstDependency(dependencies);
        final Rect available = new Rect();
        if (header != null) {
            final CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams lp =
                (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            available.set(parent.getPaddingLeft() + lp.leftMargin, header.getBottom() + lp.topMargin,
                parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight() - lp.rightMargin,
                parent.getHeight() + header.getBottom() - parent.getPaddingBottom() - lp.bottomMargin);

            final Rect out = new Rect();
            GravityCompat.apply(resolveGravity(lp.gravity), child.getMeasuredWidth(),
                child.getMeasuredHeight(), available, out, layoutDirection);
            final int overlap = getOverlapPixelsForOffset();
            child.layout(out.left, out.top - overlap, out.right, parent.getHeight() - overlap);
        }
    }

    private int getOverlapPixelsForOffset() {
        return getOverlayTop() == 0 ? 0 :
            constrain((int) (1f * getOverlayTop()), 0, getOverlayTop());
    }

    private AppBarLayout findFirstDependency(List<View> views) {
        for (int i = 0, z = views.size(); i < z; i++) {
            View view = views.get(i);
            if (view instanceof AppBarLayout) {
                return (AppBarLayout) view;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static int constrain(int amount, int low, int high) {
        return amount < low ? low : (amount > high ? high : amount);
    }

    private static int resolveGravity(int gravity) {
        return gravity == Gravity.NO_GRAVITY ? GravityCompat.START | Gravity.TOP : gravity;
    }

    private void setDimensions(CoordinatorLayout view, int width, int height) {
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private float getOffset(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout) {

        for (int i = 0; i < coordinatorLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = coordinatorLayout.getChildAt(i);

            if (child instanceof AppBarLayout) {
                return child.getY() + child.getHeight();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Solution is kind of complex, but I couldn't find any other better way to solve this. So if anyone knows better solution to this case please post and I'll investigate it.